# A car moves at a constant speed from A place to B.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions, word-problem

A car moves at a constant speed from A place to B. By $8$ o'clock in the morning the car covered $1/6$ part of the planned route, and by $11$ o'clock in the morning of the same day $8/9$ part. What part of the planned route did the
car cover by $10$ o'clock and $30$ minutes in the morning of the same day?

I tried using proportion to get the part of planned route, didn't get the right answer. Help appreciated

Comment: It's okay if you tried and didn't get the right answer.  But we can really only help you if you post your work and include it in your question, so we can see better where you may have made a mistake, so you learn.  You seem to know mathjax, so you've likely been here before. Please add your workings.

Comment: @JaimeLan Difference of fractional parts divided by time (3 hours) is your speed. So find out distance for time given inside the interval. And please show your work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Between $8$AM and $11$AM, the car covered $\dfrac89 - \dfrac16 = \dfrac{13}{18}$ of the planned route. Since this is $3$ hours, the car covers $\dfrac{13/18}{3} = \dfrac{13}{54}$ of the planned route each hour.

From $8$AM to $10$:$30$AM is $2.5$ hours, so in that time the car covers $\dfrac{13}{54}\cdot\dfrac52 = \dfrac{65}{108}$ of the planned route. Add that to the $\dfrac16$ already covered by $8$AM, and we have that at $10$:$30$AM, the car has covered $\dfrac{65}{108} + \dfrac16 = \dfrac{83}{108}$ of the planned route.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: How long is the duration between 8 am and 11 am?  What portion of the journey did the car travel in that time?